# Format a date from itemStyle.xml file

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt

I want to print date like

```
Tuesday,17 February,2015
```

I tried somethings that print dates like

```
Tuesday,17 February 2015
Tuesday, February 17, 2015
```

What I tried is:

[image]

How can I print date like `Tuesday,5 April,2016`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by making changes in date format as below

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate),3081,'dddd,d MMMM,yyyy')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned line to get your desired output.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate), 1033, 'dddd, mmmm d, yyyy')" />
```